# Accepting/Rejecting suggested edits

Tags: discussion

Today I rejected the suggested edit for [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/13578/revisions) by Freddy. First of all I think this is a way too minor edit to start with. IMO H2O is as perfectly understandable as $\ce{H2O}$. I would also not complain if it weren't for the second change. [Overvoltage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overvoltage) is a technical term, that has nothing to do with 'over voltage' - if there were to be made any change it should have been to '[overpotential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overpotential)'.
The main question coming up here is, how would one go ahead to deal with that. Because if a rejection has no vote at all, why bother checking the edit in the first place. (And following that logic, why should I then ever be checking the queue?)

Comment: You are right probably some one else has vote to approve it. I however discourage edit for trivial formatting.